# How to find all direct subclasses of a class with .NET Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Consider the following classes hierarchy: base class A, classes B and C inherited from A and class D inherited from B.

```
public class A     {...}
public class B : A {...}
public class C : A {...}
public class D : B {...}
```

I can use following code to find all subclasses of A including D:

```
var baseType = typeof(A);
var assembly = typeof(A).Assembly;
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(baseType));
```

But I need to find only direct subclasses of A (B and C in example) and exclude all classes not directly inherited from A (such as D).
Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For each of those types, check if

```
type.BaseType == typeof(A)
```

Or, you can put it directly inline:

```
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(baseType));
```

Comment: Not sure if you want `typeof(t)` there; won't that result in `System.Type` since `t` is already the `System.Type` representing `A`, `B`, `D`, etc? EDIT: No, I'm silly, that's just a compiler error instead!

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Changed to use `type` and `t` directly.  Thanks; don't have VS in front of me to verify currently.

Comment: thanks! I've missed BaseType property. Additionally, any idea how to get all first non-abstract subclasses of a class? In my sample if B is abstract then I want C and D.

Comment: @mykola: Off the top of my head, not sure how to do so without using recursion and checking [Type.IsAbstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isabstract.aspx).  You may want to start a new question for that.

Comment: @mykola: Plus, you then have you then have to consider what "first" means.  (`B : A`, `F : B`, `G : B` - if `B` is abstract and both `F` and `G` aren't, do you want a deterministic answer?  Do you want both to appear?)

Comment: Thanks, @zimdanen, I have enough info to figure it out! I need all of them. Maybe "all first" in my comment doesn't explain it well.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Type.BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) for that. From the documentation:

> The base type is the type from which the current type directly inherits. Object is the only type that does not have a base type, therefore null is returned as the base type of Object.

Answer (score 3):

Just compare them appropriately:

```
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == baseType);
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct - this would return none, assuming we're looking for descendants of `A`, because `A.BaseType` is `Object` (see **Toni Petrina**'s answer for the documentation on that).  This should be `t.BaseType == baseType` or compiling equivalent.

Comment: Right. Wasn't paying attention after first answer came in.

Answer (score 0):

.BaseType will not get you types that inherit from types that inherit.

For example if you have class B inherit from class A and class C inherit from class B. If you want all classes inheriting from A you want B and C, but checking .BaseType will only get you B. So if you want to use .BaseType you need to loop through and walk the chain to see if you encounter your desired base type somewhere along the way. Fortunately there is a better way.

a.IsAssignableFrom(b) will tell you if a variable of type b is considered type a.

So for example if B inherits from A I could do this:

```
A myVar = new B();
```

.IsAssignableFrom tells you whether this is allowed for two particular types.

Best way to remember the order is the order is the same way you write out the variable assignment (as above).

My complete code, where myType is the type you want to find all inherited types, is:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes().Where(x => myType.IsAssignableFrom(x))
```

This will also return myType itself.

If you want to only check the Assembly (DLL/EXE) that contains myType (a common case) and skip others, you can do this. I also added in the exclusion for myType so you can see it in action:

```
myType.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x != myType && myType.IsAssignableFrom(x))
```