# Iterate through sub classes of a base class and instantiate them

Tags: c#

I have one base class, and a large number of subclasses that inherit from it. I wish to create a list containing three of each of these subclass instances. At the moment I have to do:

```
List<BaseClass> bigList = new List<BaseClass>;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   bigList.Add(new A());
   bigList.Add(new B());
   etc.
```

Where A and B are two of the subclasses. Is there any way I can iterate through all of the classes without having to state them separately, something like this:

```
foreach (Class classname in listOfClasses){
   for (int i = 0; i < classname.numberToAdd; i++){
      bigList.Add(new classname());
   }
}
```

Where 'classname' will effectively be equivalent to A, B, C etc.

This would help, as the actual program is more complicated as the number added varies depending on the class in question (I may want four of A, five of B, and none of C etc).

Is there a better way of doing it altogether?
Am I just going to have to do it the long way?

Comment: I mean, you could use reflection, but it sounds like you have bigger design problems.

Comment: You need to use reflection to find your classes and instantiate new objects.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh he hasn't mentioned he wants to instantiate then.  just return a list of names.

Comment: Another solution would be to use the factory pattern with each different subclass being tied to a number.

Comment: are these all in the same assembly?

Comment: @Fran, he want. At least his code adds instances of subclasses to the list: `bigList.Add(new A());`

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh sorry about that.  i see that now.

Comment: there's a bunch of issues? do all the subclasses have a default constructor?  are they in the same assembly?  do you have to scan all assemblies in the bin?  you are going to call Activator.CreateInstance on the found types.

Comment: The lazy person in me says to use reflection.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many answered questions on Stack Overflow already that discuss enumerating types in assemblies and examining the relationships of those types, including comparing types to determine whether they are derived from some other type. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923427/given-a-base-class-how-do-i-find-the-most-specialized-subclasses-of-it and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038819/how-to-find-all-direct-subclasses-of-a-class-with-net-reflection. Your question is too broad as currently written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reflection to find all types in the assembly, and test if they derive from your base class.  You can use a custom attribute for instantiation count:

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<BaseClass> bigList = new List<BaseClass>();
            foreach (var type in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()) {
                if (typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !(type.IsAbstract)) {
                    var ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
                    if (ctor != null) {
                        var countAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(InstantiationCountAttribute)) as InstantiationCountAttribute;
                        if (countAttr != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < countAttr.Count; ++i) {
                                bigList.Add((BaseClass)ctor.Invoke(null));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var test in bigList) {
                Console.WriteLine(test.GetType().Name);
            }
        }        
    }
    abstract class BaseClass {
    }
    class InstantiationCountAttribute : Attribute {
        public InstantiationCountAttribute(int count) {
            Count = count;
        }
        public int Count { get; private set; }
    }

    [InstantiationCount(1)]
    class A : BaseClass {
    }

    [InstantiationCount(34)]
    class B : BaseClass {
    }
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks. However is it possible to use a property of the subclasses rather than an attribute to store the instantiation count?

Comment: Yes.  Make an abstract property in the base class for the count.  You would then instantiate the first one, query the count, and determine how many more to instantiate and/or add.